# Spring Boot external Tomcat and external application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, application.properties

i created a new spring boot application.
For development i use the default "appilcation.propperties" for my configuration.

But for production i want to have a external configuration file, because this application will run on multiple tomcats. So i want to have a "application.properties" on every tomcat.

EG:

"SERVER/TOMCAT1_ROOT/conf/application.propperties"

"SERVER/TOMCAT2_ROOT/conf/application.propperties"

Now i thought i can add this path dynamicly in my default "application.propperties":

```
spring.config.additional-location=file:${CATALINA_HOME}/conf/application.properties
```

But this line is not parsable. So is there any way to include a path dynamicly?

Comment: What is the error?  According to the [guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-placeholders-in-properties) it hould work.  Is CATALINA_HOME a defined environment variable for the server?

Comment: CATALINA_HOME is an enviroment variable which will be created when the tomcat server starts. So it's no placeholder within my application.properties